If we put a manometer in a tube where a fluid is in motion will we measure the static pressure or the dynamic pressure?
I got confused between dynamic pressure and static one, I want to understand several things

when we measure the pressure of a flowing fluid, will we be measuring static or dynamic pressure?

when a flowing fluid impacts on a solid surface or boundary, do the both pressures exert forces to the solid boundary, or it is only the static pressure, or the dynamic pressure only



I would add a slightly different application here, which might confuse things - aviation. It is meant to illustrate though.
In aeroplanes we have two measurements that are converted and calculated and shown to the pilot on instruments. All this will be a  simplification but should suffice for this discussion.  The static pressure is measured by a static port and connected to instruments via tubes. This is used to show the altitude the plane is at. Higher up, the static pressure is lower and this will be reflected on the altimeter showing a higher value. In order to get a good reading the static port has to be very carefully placed on the body of the airplane. Any "wind" from the forward motion will create an error in the indicated altitude. (The altimeter additionally has a way to adjust for current air pressure as that changes with current weather).
The second measurement is done with a pitot tube placed in the "wind" of the aeroplane. This will give what is generally called the dynamic pressure, to be exact however it is the sum of static plus dynamic pressure. The faster the plane moves, the higher the dynamic part is. The airspeed of the plane can be calculated by subtracting the static pressure from this measurement and will be shown on the airspeed indicator. Higher dynamic pressure indicates higher speed. Again the placement of this pitot tube and its direction is very critical to get a good reading. As a gross exemple, pointing the pitot tube backwards will indicate a negativ speed (as the dynamic part of the pressure will be negative). (In the real world, especially for planes moving close or above the speed of sound, further corrections need to calculated to get correct reading).
So in short the aeroplane has two different measurements, often on different places: static pressure and static + dynamic pressure.

Manometers and other pressure measuring devices only measure static pressure. What we call static pressure is the only "real pressure" of the fluid, i.e. the mechanical potential energy per volume of fluid. Dynamic pressure is the bulk kinetic energy. We call it "dynamic pressure" but it is energy that is not currently contributing to the pressure, but could contribute if the fluid is brought to rest without energy losses (i.e. converted to static pressure).  In your example of flow impinging on a plate, the plate feels the static pressure of the moving fluid plus the static pressure that came from converting the motion of the fluid (dynamic pressure) to being static.
You might also hear of stagnation pressure, which is the total energy of the fluid (potential and kinetic) per volume, and corresponds to the static pressure the fluid has if it is at rest.
